# Is it correct to use name or brand between "the" and "one"?

Tags: responses

If there is a question:

> Which camera do you want? (in this case only the owner's name differentiating them)

Can it be answered: We want the Cindy one?

Answer (score 2):

The following examples are colloquial/informal English, but best to avoid these in formal English.

For names of people, no.

If you mean the same brand of camera which Cindy owns, then something like this would do:

- *We want the same one [that] Cindy has.*

Note: *[that]* can be omitted in the first example above.

You could also use the possessive like this:

- *We want the same [one] as Cindy's*

Note: In the example above, [one] can be omitted.

If it's a brand name, then yes it's fine to use the brand name before *one.*

- *We  want the Canon one.*

Answer (score 0):

Purely my point of view is that it's better to avoid your way and instead say:

- What camera do you want? - I want the (that) one Cindy has. (or Cindy's got).
- What camera do you want? - I want the one made by Canon.

Otherwise:

With brand names you can place it the way you mention. However, with people's names this isn't correct:

- <s>What camera do you want? - I want the Cindy's one.</s>
- Whose camera do you want? - I want Cindy's. *(the camera that Cindy owns)*
- What camera do you want? - I want the Canon one.